# Timer for earlier versions of iOS 10? (Xcode 8, Swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I'm so confused! When I initialize `NSTimer()` Xcode tells me it's been renamed to `Timer()` and if I initialize `Timer()` Xcode tells me it's only available for iOS 10.0 or later. What am I supposed to use if I want to use a timer for earlier versions of iOS?! The strangest thing to me is that no one else seems to be having this problem, so what am I missing here? What am I doing wrong?

Yes, I understand `NSTimer()` got renamed to `Timer()` in Swift 3, that's literally what I quoted from Xcode's warning message in my first sentence, so I have no idea why everyone felt the urge to 'correct' me on that. Second, it turns out there's only one type method left, which I can use for pre-iOS 10 devices, which is `Timer(timeInterval: <#T##TimeInterval#>, target: <#T##Any#>, selector: <#T##Selector#>, userInfo: <#T##Any?#>, repeats: <#T##Bool#>)`. The other 4 type methods available all pop up a warning that it's only available in iOS 10, as you can see here:
[image: Screenshot of Xcode warning]

Also, there is no class method `scheduledTimer()` available, even though I do remember it used to be their in Swift 2.2. There aren't any class methods available to a `timer` object, which means the only available type method mentioned above is the only option I have.

Comment: That code will crash if you try to run your app under iOS 9 or earlier.

Comment: @rmaddy Uhm... What question are you replying to?

Comment: Yours. Your app supports iOS 9, right? But you are attempting to use an iOS 10 only API. That's why Xcode is complaining. If you attempt to use an iOS 10 only API in your app without proper protection, then your app will crash when run under iOS 9.

Comment: @rmaddy But where did you see me ask what the warning means?

Comment: Your entire question is about the messages you are seeing in Xcode trying to create a Timer.

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah but the question was how I can use a timer without seeing those messages, I never asked what those messages mean.

Comment: Understanding why you get the message allows you to solve it. Basically, use the proper method that has existed since your app's Deployment Target.

Comment: This question is just getting worse.

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah I got that. THAT was my question, what "proper method" to use for my deployment target. Now how was your first comment an answer to this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Timer *is* NSTimer. It is not new in iOS 10.

> if I initialize Timer()

You should *never* initialize Timer by saying `Timer()`. You must call the class method `scheduledTimer(timeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:)`.

What *is* new in iOS 10 is the class method `scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval:repeats:block:)`. You can't call that in iOS 9 and before. But you don't have to. Just call `scheduledTimer(timeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats:)` in both iOS 9 and iOS 10, and all will be well.

Comment: I tried everything and there aren't any class methods. There are 5 type methods and only one of them is compatible with earlier versions of iOS 10. See my updated post for more information.

Comment: "there aren't any class methods" Fiddle-faddle. Look on this: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/timer/1412416-scheduledtimer Notice anything? Class method (`class func`). And that is what I said to call. It is not new in iOS 10 and it is what you should call. And that is what my answer said. What's the problem here?

Comment: That's a type method, and I was referring to an instance method, which I was confusing with a "class method" (as you call it). From my first comment on your answer, you could have noticed that I mistakened class methods and type methods to be two different things. What I meant to say was it doesn't have any instance methods.

Comment: That's irrelevant. I didn't tell you to call an instance method. And it does have instance methods, like `invalidate`.

Comment: I know you didn't tell me to call an instance method, that's literally what I said in my previous comment. I wasn't aware of the fact you were referring to a type method with "class method", so when you said to call the scheduledTimer class method, I thought I was supposed to find it in the timer's instance methods. And when I said it doesn't have any have any instance methods, I was referring to the methods for initializing a new timer, which it doesn't. Just a simple matter of slight miscommunication, nothing complicated about it.

Comment: That's not the point. The point is: why isn't my answer the right answer? You were having some sort of problem, right? I believe I solved it for you. You were doing something wrong. I told you how to do it right.

Comment: Oh yeah, the problem is solved. I never said your answer isn't the right answer, I just pointed out what went wrong and forgot to mention the issue was solved. Thought you were caught up to that, but it turns out you weren't. Sorry.

Comment: If the issue is solved, you should accept _some_ answer, even if it's not mine, so we can all go home. The reason we are all breezing on like this is that you have failed to do that.

Comment: Yeah I'll accept yours, but to be completely honest, the reason I hadn't accepted any answers yet was because I figured out what I was doing wrong before I even read the first answer, including yours. Truth is, I came to Stack with my question way too soon, despite the fact that I've been dealing with this issue for a couple of weeks now. I couldn't believe the solution to a problem I was trying to solve for so long would be something as simple and stupid as this.

Comment: Can you show how to call this? I'm getting "ambiguous reference calls for this: Timer.scheduledTimer(
                    timeInterval: 50.milliseconds(),
                    target: #selector(controlTimerTriggered),
                    userInfo: nil,
                    repeats: true)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have got it a bit wrong, `Timer()` is the new syntax for Swift 3.0, not for any iOS version. Swift 3.0 works for iOS 8,9,10. While `NSTimer` is used for Swift 2.2 and lower. So make sure you have deployment target 8,9 or 10 and you´ll be fine.

Comment: I understand that. That wasn't my issue, though. I updated my post, so maybe my problem makes a little more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to use exact same method without `block` and with other parameters (`target`, `selector` and `userInfo`).

I just did:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //your stuff....
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2, target: self, selector: #selector(doSomeStuff), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

@objc func doSomeStuff() {
    //your stuff....
}
```

Here are swift versions equivalents:

```
// Swift >=3 selector syntax
let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(self.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
// Swift 2.2 selector syntax
let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: #selector(MyClass.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
// Swift <2.2 selector syntax
let timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

You have to use a function for `selector` with `@objc`:

```
@objc func doSomeStuff() {
    //your stuff....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a new alias for NSTimer() for swift3.  Yiu can use it for all ios versions

Read this nice article https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift3